# "Request payload size exceeds the limit" error when exporting image from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a shapefile with multi-polygons and when I export an image of the area through Google Earth Engine this message appears:

> "Request payload size exceeds the limit:41943304 bytes".

The problem was the availability of multi-polygons in one shapefile. Is there any procedure to solve the issue?

Here is the code:

```
Map.centerObject(AOI, 9)
var ndviParams ={min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'FCD163', '66A000', '207401','056201', '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011301']};
var sentinal=ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
var nir11 = image11.select('B8');
var red11 = image11.select('B4');
var ndvi11 = nir11.subtract(red11).divide(nir11.add(red11)).rename('NDVI').clip(A);
Map.addLayer(ndvi11, ndviParams, 'NDVI November');
Export.image.toDrive({image: ndvi11,description: 'NDVI_Nov',maxPixels: 3e12,scale:
```

Comment: In your code, what is `AOI`?  What is `A` in `.clip(A)`?  Where is the multi-polygon shapefile?  Did you ingest it?  You are exporting an image here.  You should specify a region in the export.  If `A` is a `FeatureCollection`, use `clipToCollection()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message means that the process request sent to Earth Engine servers is really large. Common culprits include: (a) a large amount of data (e.g., very complex geometries, large arrays) included in the script, and/or (b) the script has client-side loops that could be server-side loops, which has the effect of replicating a large, complex expression on each iteration.

Your code is not reproducible (see Nick's comment) so it is hard to diagnose the problem well. My guess is it stems from clipping by a complex `Geometry` or `FeatureCollection` on this line:

```js
var ndvi11 = nir11.subtract(red11).divide(nir11.add(red11)).rename('NDVI').clip(A);
```

Try clipping with `clipToCollection(A)`, if `A` is a `FeatureCollection`. Also, don't clip, if you don't need to. You can specify a region to export when calling `Export.image.toDrive` using the `region` parameter. It will accept a `FeatureCollection`, `Feature`, or `Geometry` object. Note that `region` should always be set when exporting because if not specified, the region exported defaults to the viewport (Map extent) at the time of invocation.