# Does study area complexity (number of vertices) affect imagery downloading time in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Will imagery mapped(clipped) to a polygon ROI consisting of thousands or tens of thousands of vertices be processed and downloaded at the similar rate as a rectangular study area of similar area?

If my study area is a very complex shape, will it be more time-efficient to download a simpler processed image collection and then batch-clip the imagery in GIS software.

Comment: What have you already tried? I imagine you can set-up a small experiment for yourself with less vertices under the assumption that the processing time increases with the number of vertices.

Comment: It shouldn't add too much processing time. However in the case you are using a complex geometry in the export call it might lead to issues. See the answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370311/earth-engine-payload-request-exceeded-on-export/370604#370604